# Elasticsearch tokenize outside the double quotes

Tags: elasticsearch, search, elasticsearch-analyzers

I have elasticsearch with a mapping created as follows.

```
PUT /test
{
  "settings":{
      "analysis":{
         "analyzer":{
            "my_analyzer":{
               "filter":[
                  "lowercase"
               ],
               "type":"custom",
               "tokenizer":"my_tokenizer"
            }
         },
         "tokenizer": {
           "my_tokenizer": {
             "type": "char_group",
             "tokenize_on_chars": [
                "whitespace",
                ":"
              ]
           }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings":{
      "properties":{
         "data":{
            "type":"text",
            "analyzer":"my_analyzer"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

What i want to do is create a new token on encountering the : character and remove it from the data. But i only want to do this if it is outside double quotes ("). Is there any way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

Imho you could either try to express it using regexp and pattern tokenizer (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-tokenizer.html) or ... go through the hell of writing the tokenizer yourself and trying to add it to your elasticsearch instalation.

Comment: I think i'll just let that happen. It's not a major issue anyway, and i did see the pattern tokenizer but didn't go through that because of performance reasons. And writing my own elasticsearch java tokenizer, not really :P. Particularly cause it's java. Thanks for the answer.